# CUDA: --ptxas-options=-v shared memory and cudaFuncAttributes.sharedSizeBytes do not match

Tags: c++, c, cuda, ptxas

I'm trying to use `reqRegs` and `sharedSizeBytes` in the `cudaFuncAttributes` struct to dynamically optimise a kernel's block size at runtime.

My current implementation skims the stdout text from `nvcc --ptxas-options=-v` to discover the register and shared memory usage of the kernel. This method is a little hacky, and is dependent on the exact format of output text from `--ptxas-options=-v`, which could change without warning.

My problem is that I'm seeing a discrepancy between the 'smem' shared memory value reported in the `--ptxas-options=-v` output, and `sharedSizeBytes` in the `cudaFuncAttributes` struct, which has me worried that either the shared memory estimation I have been using until now is wrong, or that the `sharedSizeBytes` variable is unreliable, meaning I cannot use it for the purposes of runtime block size optimisation. 
Here is the output of `nvcc --ptxas-options=-v` for one such kernel ...

```
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 2088 bytes smem, 48 bytes cmem[1]
```

... compared with the value of `cudaFuncAttributes.sharedSizeBytes` = 296 at runtime, for the exact same kernel. Does anybody know what could be happening here?

Here is another example with a different kernel:

```
ptxas info    : Used 18 registers, 2132 bytes smem, 48 bytes cmem[1]
```

where `cudaFuncAttributes.sharedSizeBytes` = 340 at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: Some optimizations might be using unused shared memory, which cc are you compiling for?

Comment: I wrote [a simple test](http://pastebin.com/JWsLGvrn) and was not able to observe this discrepancy.  Can you please provide a complete test case, hopefully as simple as mine, that demonstrates this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Robert and Marco for your replies. They helped me to rule out a few cases.

It turns out that the mismatch in reported shared memory usage resulted from the amount of shared memory used after the first test compile (reported by `--ptxas-options=-v`) being different from the amount of shared memory being used by the final program with revised block size (reported by `cudaFuncAttributes.sharedSizeBytes`). (EDIT for clarity)

The shared memory difference was caused by shared memory array allocations being dependent on block size; for example:

```
__shared__ float myArray[BLOCK_SIZE];
```

The statement above uses a different amount of shared memory, in a program with a block size of 256, than the same source code compiled with an optimised block size of 192. It seems obvious now, but something to watch out for in optimised CUDA code generation.

Comment: Regarding your answer, the one line of code you have shown is a static allocation, which means the size (`BLOCK_SIZE`) must be known at compile-time.  There would be no discrepancy between the compile-time output and the run-time output for this either. (You still have not shown an example demonstrating a discrepancy.  There is none.) The only discrepancy you could run into is scanning the *wrong* (i.e. old, stale, previous) compile time output for the kernel in question.

Comment: That was my point, sir. The first call to `nvcc` was using a different value for `BLOCK_SIZE` than the second `nvcc` call. Therefore, the amount of shared memory used by the first program is different from that used by the second.